# Learning Javascript - Is this a messy implementation of a Javascript Slider?

Tags: javascript

I've been learning JS for a few months now and I've just finished creating a small image slider for a website. The sliders functionality is as follows:

- Continuously cycle through images and loop back to the start
- Allow the user to click through to a certain section
- When clicked, the cycle timer must reset and the loop must continue from that point

  - cycle through a corresponding DOM element (in this case it's a testimonial quote)

I'm mainly looking for pointers on how to make my code more efficient or if I've used bad practice. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('slide-container');
var button = document.getElementById('slider-buttons');
var quote = document.getElementById('quote-container');
var interval = 0;

sliderMove = function(position){

  // Move container to next image
  container.style.left = -(350 * position) + 'px';

  // Remove active classes from all children
  for (var i = 0; i < quote.children.length; i++) {
    quote.children[i].classList.remove("quote-active");
    button.children[i].classList.remove('active');
  };

  // Add active classes to specified children
  quote.children[position].classList.add("quote-active");
  button.children[position].classList.add('active');

  // Increase global interval variable by 1
  interval++;

  // Set interval back to 0 if it exceeds the amount of quotes
  if (interval >= quote.children.length) {
    interval = 0;
  };
};


// Add event listener to buttons
button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  clearInterval(timer); // Resets timer when user clicks on an image
  autoMove(); // Restarts timer
  if (event.target.id > -1) { // Ensures the target is valid
    interval = event.target.id;
    sliderMove(interval);
  };
});

// Auto Rotate
function autoMove(index) {
  timer = setInterval(function(){
    index = interval;
    sliderMove(index);
  },5000);
}

autoMove(0);
sliderMove(0);
```

Comment: Have you checked your code with javascript lint (plugins would be available , you can use with VSCode or your favourite editor). Please check.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, Lachlan! Could you include a working example of your HTML and CSS in the post as well? It looks like the JavaScript is dependent on the HTML and CSS to function as expected. Note that you can use the JavaScript/HTML/CSS Snippet function (Ctrl+M) to add "live" HTML/JS to your post.